# Counting number of occurences of tuples in an m:n relationship

Tags: sql

I'd like to know if there's an efficient way to count the number of occurences of a permutation of entities from one side of the m:n relationship. Hopefully, the next example will illustrate properly what I mean:


Let's imagine a base with people and events of some sort. People can organize multiple events and events can be organized by more than one person. What i'd like to count is whether a certain tuple of people have already organized an event or if it's their first time. My first idea to do this is to add an attribute to the m:n relationship

```
PeopleID | EventID | TimesOrganized
100        1         1
200        1         1
300        2         1
400        3         1
```

Now, there's an event no. 4 that's again organized by persons 200 and 100 (let's say they should be added in that order). The new table should look like:

```
PeopleID | EventID | TimesOrganized
100        1         2
200        1         2
300        2         1
400        3         1
200        4         2
100        4         2
```

Now, if I added an event organized by persons 200 and 300 it would look like this:

```
PeopleID | EventID | TimesOrganized
100        1         2
200        1         2
300        2         1
400        3         1
200        4         2
100        4         2
200        5         1
300        5         1
```

How would I go about keeping the third column updated properly and what are my options?

I should also add that this a part of the larger project we have for one of the classes and we'll be implementing an application that uses the database in some way, so I might as well move this to application logic if there's no easy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend tracking a TimesOrganized column as you suggest.

You can simple query it as needed using a COUNT(EventId)..GROUP BY PeopleID.

If you do feel you need to maintain the value somewhere it probably is better normalized to the (presumed) table People. Something like People.TimesOrganized. But then you have to increment it as you go instead of just recalculating as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count how many many time someone have organized an event the problem is not m:n, but 1:m. Just count the event grouped by the people, that's it, you don't really need to have that column in the table, if it's not needed a lot of time.

That said I find you table a little confusing, there are detail and aggregation mixed, the third one downright wrong: the PeopleID 200 had organized 3 event and the 300 have 2 event.